# Number of ways to obtain 10 boy-girl pairs from $10$ boys and $10$ girls

Tags: combinatorics

Is the number of ways to obtain $10$ boy-girl pairs from $10$ boys and $10$ girls equal to $\frac{(10!)^2}{10!}$? My reasoning is as follows:
We first perform an ordered selection of 10 boys and ordered selection of $10$ girls, and then we pair the $i$th boy we chose to the $i$th girl we chose. The number of ways to do this is $(10!)^2$. However, by doing this, we actually count the total number of ordered pairs of boys and girls, but we want unordered pairs of boys and girls, so we then divide by $10!$.

Comment: Yes, this is right.  A slightly different way to think about:  arrange the $10$ boys in a line however you like.  Then there are $10!$ ways to arrange the girls in a parallel line, and all pairings arise this way.

Comment: @lulu Thank you!

Comment: @lulu elegant !!

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct. However, the solution could be simpler.

Thinking from the perspective of boys, the first boy (could be anyone, the order doesn't matter) can be paired with any of the $10$ girls. The second boy with any of the remaining $9$ girls. And so on.

So, the total number $10!$.